# Plugins not working in JW6

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am trying to create a plugin for the JW6 player and found some documentation [here](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/export/2603/sdks/jw6-plugin-sdk/docs/plugins-js.pdf)

I tried following the instructions and created an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gdBHK/2/)

I added the plugin to the player using the plugin option

```
plugins: {
    "http://izaazyunus.cloudapp.net/js/plugin.js": {
        text: 'Hello all!'
    }
},
```

I see that the register plugin method is being called, but the plugin template function is not getting called.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide a link to where this is running.

Comment: The link to the fiddle has it. You can also find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gdBHK/2/)

Comment: Got it working! I replaced the url of the plugin with the plugin name and it worked fine!

Comment: Glad you got it working!